# How do you call a function in a function using std::?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<char>function(std::string word) {
}

namespace::json getList(){
function();
}
```

I was just wondering if im suppose to call the function on top by including std::function(argument)

Comment: No, you are not supposed to use `std::function`. Why do you ask? Do you see any compiler errors?

Comment: well im suppose to call a shuffle function into the getlist function. In my get list function i have result.push_back. I have everything correct for the shuffle function just not sure how to call it within the getlist function.

Comment: Please write valid C++ in the example.

Comment: Then, please post a [mcve]. It's hard to suggest something constructive with bits and pieces of code.

Comment: I suspect there's confusion here over your calling your function `function` instead of a name that doesn't share that of a class in the standard library.

Comment: Your question still does not contain an explanation of why you believe your current code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need nor should you use the `std::function` class to call `function`. The `std::function` class is more like a function pointer wrapper. It lets you work with functions as data more easily.

For example, `std::function<T> func` represents *some* parameterless function that returns an object of type `T`.

Refer to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for `std::function` for more information.

Comment: I feel like the question actually was asking about calling/declaring functions in different namespaces. I don't think he even knew about `std::function` being a thing - just poor naming